# button to select which style sheet to use

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, multiple-instances

I am making a restaurant WP Woocommerce site that is for delivery or pickup.  Is there a way to place a button on the site landing page to decide which style-sheet to use site-wide; style-sheet-1, add to cart buttons or style-sheet-2, display-none add to cart buttons?

-Chad

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create multiple stylesheets, one for each color/style you want the theme to have. You can then create a settings menu on your theme with different color options. When the user selects an option it will select that specific stylesheet which can be injected into the theme 'head' using jquery.

So for example a normal stylesheet would be linked like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
...
```

You could then use jquery to apply a different stylesheet when the setting button is clicked like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("settingButton").click(function () {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="newstylesheet.css" type="text/css" />');
    });
});
```

This would add a new CSS Styesheet to the head.

Alternativley you could replace the old stylesheet all together, by removing its link and replacing it with the new one by using something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("settingButton").click(function () {
            $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith('<link href="newstylesheet.css" ');
        });
    });
```

I hope this helps :)